# Letter accents, Ubuntu Studio 20.10, KDE Plasma, Lenovo P14s

Tags: keyboard

I am trying without success to configure the French azerty keyboard on my Lenovo P14s/20.10/KDE Plasma so that the accents work. For example, if I type ^ followed by e, the result should be one letter : the e underneath the ^ accent.

When setting the keyboard in "configuration du système" I can select one of several keyboard models, none of which is my P14s but I come close. I also select an appropriate "disposition" (which may be called "profile" or "layout"in English); either "French (Macintosh)" or French (AZERTY) seem appropriate.

When I apply these settings and then test it out, the accents work fine for a moment. But they stop working, seemingly as soon as I exit system configuration or otherwise use another program.

EDIT : I've looked into the usr/share/X11/xkb directory and subdirectories and it seems the configuration files are here. I can track changes I make via system configuration gui with what I see here, and the changes are properly reported via `setxkbmap -query`.

For example, immediately after making the keyboard settings, the keyboard works properly with accents and this is reported via `$ setxkbmap -query` :

`rules:      evdev`

`model:      thinkpad60`

`layout:     fr`

`variant:    oss_sundeadkeys`

However, soon afterwards the keyboard stops working for accents and this is reported via `$ setxkbmap -query` :

`rules:      evdev`

`model:      thinkpad60`

`layout:     fr,fr`

`variant:    oss_nodeadkeys,oss_sundeadkeys`

This is quite maddening.

EDIT2: When I run the following command the exact same behavior results : `$ setxkbmap -variant oss-sundeadkeys` The keyboard works fine and then does not, because the system automatically adds another layout with the `oss_nodeadkeys` variant.

Does anyone know how I can prevent my system from adding another layout and the `oss_nodeadkeys` variant and instead make it stick to the settings I have chosen (apart from somehow deleting `oss_nodeadkeys` completely from my system, as I am afraid of messing things up and losing my keyboard function completely upon a reboot) ????

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help !

Comment: Have you installed Tweaks? You can set the right Win key as a compose key and then you will be able to use Rt Win + e + ^ to produce ê and other accented chars.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I was hoping to avoid using a compose key since I should be able to get this working. I had it working correctly under KDE neon while I was waiting for Ubuntu Studio to appear with KDE Plasma, but it has not worked under my Ubuntu Studio. If I can't get it working I'll try Tweaks. Thanks again.

Comment: If you need further help come back. I use a UK Keyboard to type French chars a lot (living in France) and the `compose` key latching makes it much easier to follow without having to do finger acrobatics.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again !

Comment: Yes I use a UK keyboard with a compose key too - I find it works very well for accented letters. (In my case it's a Sun Microsystems Type 7 keyboard, which has a real key labelled Compose).

Comment: Thanks B. Tanner. Another reason I'd like to fix this with normal configuration is that my keyboard is a french azerty with standard accented keys such as é, è à, ù, ç. But I need the circumflex ^ above some letters, for example the word "être" is commonly used. I can type that now, but my system will soon default to another layout with the oss_nodeadkeys variant. But I'll wait another day or two and if no solution emerges, then I'll follow the advice of 24601 and yourself. Grazie !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a bug with the KDE Plasma implementation in Ubuntu Studio 20.10. For instance, `oss-sundeadkeys` might not be the same as `oss_sundeadkeys`. Or maybe I am doing something wrong somewhere.

I'll keep checking here for help, but in the meantime I'll have my system automatically run the terminal command `setxkbmap -variant oss-sundeadkeys` upon reboot or startup.

EDIT: I've modified the terminal command upon reboot or startup to be : `setxkbmap -option compose:lwin -variant oss-sundeadkeys` because doing so adds accents for capital letters via compose key which I would not have even if my keyboard had been working properly with accents (I still need `setxkbmap -option oss-sundeadkeys` to have circumflex letters such as ê, â, î, ô, û). And I thank 24601 and B. Tanner again for their help, because without their suggestions I would not have otherwise configured the compose key today. Incidentally, the `setxkbmap -option compose:lwin` command is necessary despite this being available as a system configuration option for the compose key with KDE Plasma. As with my desired keyboard variant there seems to be  a problem which negates the changes made for compose key in system configuration; those compose key changes work, initially, but soon stop working.

In case this helps anyone else, here is the output from `$ setxkbmap -query` which now seems to persist without requiring another execution of `setxkbmap -option compose:lwin -variant oss-sundeadkeys` during a session :

`rules:      evdev`

`model:      thinkpad60`

`layout:     fr,fr`

`variant:    oss-sundeadkeys`

`options:    compose:lwin`

Grazie !!!